# How to resolve this error in python script for extracting twitter tweets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, twitter

I'm using python3 but the code here is for python2. I'm getting an error while running the code. I have to get the tweets from twitter.
I have installed tweepy but still getting an error.
My access key, consumer key and consumer secret key is correct. How can I resolve that problem. Is it any alternate way to resolve this issue?

```
import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import csv

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = "xxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxx"
access_key = "xxxx"
access_secret = "xxxx"


def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
#Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

#authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
alltweets = []

#make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name,count=200)

#save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

#save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

#keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
print ("getting tweets before %s" % (oldest))

#all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)
#save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)`enter code here`

#update the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

print("...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets)))

#transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]
#write the csv
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
writer.writerows(outtweets)


pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
#pass in the username of the account you want to download
get_all_tweets("ArsalanBajwa")

'


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e2a778291283> in <module>()
     21 
     22 #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
---> 23 new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name,count=200)
     24 
     25 #save most recent tweets

NameError: name 'api' is not defined

how to resolve it?
```

[Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1G1r.png)

Comment: Is your code not idented, or is it just while copying it on SO that it got un-indented ?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it in caps, I've had this error, that's how I fixed it.

new_tweets = API.user_timeline(screen_name,count=200)